# py2neo (Neo4j) bulk operation

Tags: neo4j, py2neo, knowledge-graph

I have created a nice graph using Neo4j Desktop, using a local CSV file that I added to the project. now I'm trying to use python to do that automatically for that I'm trying to use methods from here https://py2neo.org/2021.1/bulk/index.html like create/merge nodes/relatioships.
I have 2 questions,

1. Do I need to use create method (create node for exmaple) and after that to use merge method (merge nodes for this example) or can use merge nodes from the begining?
   I have tried to use merge only and I got some wierd things when I'm using large sample size.

2)After creation of nodes and relationships how can I change the visualization of the nodes (put some value in the node)?

*If there is an other way to use python to create graph from a big CSV file I would like to hear, Thanks!